# DB2 query error during the retrieval of a CLOB field

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, db2, clob

From Java I am doing the following query on DB2:

```
SELECT * FROM PRV_PRE_ACTIVATION WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = ?
```

The field `TRANSACTION_ID` is a `VARCHAR` of length 32. I set the parameter in the preparedStatement using the `setString` method.

I get the error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=63, DRIVER=3.59.81
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:676)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bn.c(bn.java:2546)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bn.d(bn.java:2534)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bn.a(bn.java:2026)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.g(cb.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:40)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.i(rb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bn.gb(bn.java:1997)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cn.pc(cn.java:3009)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cn.b(cn.java:3786)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cn.bc(cn.java:678)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cn.executeQuery(cn.java:652)
```

Where the sqstate means "Capability is not supported by this version of the DB2 application requester, DB2 application server, or the combination of the two." But I don't use any strange functionality.

I have tried using  an squ client the query:

```
SELECT * FROM PRV_PRE_ACTIVATION where transaction_id='A'
```

And it goes ok.

What is the cause of the problem?

UPDATE: The code where the statement is prepared:

```
s = con.prepareStatement(sSQL,
                 ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                 ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Comment: can you show the code where you initialize the preparedStatement

Comment: Can you execute "SELECT * FROM PRV_PRE_ACTIVATION" from your Java code?  Your problem might be a connection problem, rather than an SQL problem.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes, I execute many other queries on the same datasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to a specified list of columns in the select list -- my guess is you have a user defined column type (or some other type) which is not supported by your driver.  For example, does the statement

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID FROM PRV_PRE_ACTIVATION WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = ?
```

work?  If so then start adding columns in and you will find the problem column.

Comment: Thank you! The query that you wrote works. I have noticed that one of the fields is a CLOB. I believe that is the probem.

Comment: Yes, CLOB is not supported as a select list item.

Answer (score 2):

I've came across this problem lately, and after some searching on web, I've came across this link: 
[DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -270, SQLSTATE: 42997, SQLERRMC: 63](http://www.databaseteam.org/9-db2/64ffebaa0c9e113d.htm)
, which specifies this:

> A column with a LOB type, distinct type on a LOB type, or
>       structured type cannot be specified in the select-list of an
>       insensitive scrollable cursor.

With help from an colleague, we came to this conclusion:

1, Q: When will you get this "SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704" exception?

A: When a scrollable PreparedStatement is prepared & executed, yet there are [B|C]LOB fields exist in the select list. e.g.:

```
String strQuery = "SELECT NUMBER_FIELD, CHAR_FIELD, CLOB_FIELD FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITION IS TRUE;"
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, REsultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery); //and this exception will be thrown here
```

2, Q: So what's the solution if we want to get rid of it when [B|C]LOB fields are queried?

A: Try to use ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY while creating the query statement.e.g.:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Or simply try this one:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Note that the same rules apply to conn.prepareStatement() too. You may refer to [Java API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) for more information.

Comment: This is a more detailed answer than the accepted, plus it offers a better solution.