# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270 exception thrown by jpa paging item reader

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I have created a spring batch service with a item reader, item processor and item writer.I have extended the AbstractPagingItemReader and created my own implementation by the name of JpaPagingItemReader.Now when I ran the batch service the reader reads a fix set of records from db (default page size: 10),processes them and writes them.However on second read it throws me the below  exception:

```
2015-06-25 16:33:00,712 ERROR [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-6][saeedh:120659] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=63, DRIVER=3.61.65
2015-06-25 16:33:00,712 ERROR [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-6][saeedh:120659] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-270;42997;63, DRIVER=3.61.65
2015-06-25 16:33:00,712 ERROR [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-6][saeedh:120659] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-270;42997;63, DRIVER=3.61.65
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=63, DRIVER=3.61.65
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:676)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gn.c(gn.java:2554)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gn.d(gn.java:2542)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gn.a(gn.java:2034)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hn.a(hn.java:6500)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.g(cb.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:40)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.i(rb.java:135)
```

I get that this error is probably because there is a CLOB column in the table from where I am reading records but the weird thing is it reads the first batch of 10 records fine,process them and write them but on second time read it throws the above exception.Any suggestions?Below is a snippet from JpaPagingItemReader that I wrote.The override doReadPage method from AbstractPagingItemReader.java.

```
protected void doReadPage ()
    {
        setPageSize (10);
        // Flush we already have in entity manager
        getEntityManager ().flush ();

        // clear the entity manager: To read and detach
        getEntityManager ().clear ();

        Query query = createQuery ().setFirstResult (getPage () * getPageSize ()).setMaxResults (getPageSize ());

        if (parameterValues != null)
        {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> me : parameterValues.entrySet ())
            {
                query.setParameter (me.getKey (), me.getValue ());
            }
        }

        if (results == null)
        {
            results = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<T> ();
        }
        else
        {
            results.clear ();
        }

        results.addAll (query.getResultList ());

        // Detach all objects that became part of persistence context
        getEntityManager ().clear ();

    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated as I already behind deadline due to this issue.Please if you think any thing is missing,do let me know and I will update the question.Thanks.

Comment: maybe this CLOB is null on the first few rows? Love databases that are too lazy to give a message and just expect people to somehow lookup some error code ...

Comment: Thanks.No I double checked it.The query is fine.I also run it in the DB2 client and it gave me correct results.I even tried puttin @lob annotation on data field in model object but no change.I am still getting the same exception on every second read of records regardless what the page size I set.If it is 10 then for next 10 records it is exception,if it is 2 then on next 2 records it is exception.

Comment: did you already looked around e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686832/db2-query-error-during-the-retrieval-of-a-clob-field ?

Comment: Yes @MIchael I did come across the link you provided but my situation is bit different.In my case I can read the first batch of records from db and my Clob data read fine.I can process those individual records and write them where I want.But on second read I get the exception which is a bit weird.

Comment: did you try to read the data from the second chunk with database tools? maybe its the data itself

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.The issue was indeed that we are not allowed to have Clob data as a projection in a scrollable JPA cursor.The first 10 records are read just fine but as soon as It starts to read the second batch it has to move the cursor from 0 to the 11th record.That is when I was getting sql exception.

Simple fix was to remove the CLOB column from the select statement and get it in a separate query where its value is required.That fixed my problem.Thanks.